# Задача js (массив,сумма индексов и значений которых четна)

Tags: javascript

Вывести элементы данного массива, сумма индексов и значений которых    четна. я тут получил все четные числа(2,4,8), и сколько их там (3)
но сумму не могу получить, как писать без indexOf?

```
       let x = [2,4,5,8,1]
       let x = 0
       for(i=0;i<x.length;i++){
        if(x[i]%2==0){
            console.log(x[i])
            x++
        }
    }
    console.log(x)


так тоже не работает

let arr4 = [2,4,5,8,1]
let x = 0
for(i=0;i<arr4.length;i++){
    if(x+arr4[i]%2==0){
        console.log(arr4[i])
        x++
    }
}
console.log(x)
```

Comment: отлично, дерзайте! можете еще посмотреть соседний вопрос по тегу, как надо оформлять подобные вопросы.

Comment: не знаю, что там такое у вас "пара". подозреваю, что четна. Если у вас сказано, сложить индекс со значением и проверить, то почему вы проверяете только значение?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Что-то такое?

Первый вариант проверяет четность значения и индекса если считать индекс с 1

второй если с 0.

Получается четность суммы это `( item + index + 1 ) % 2 === 0`   либо `( item + index ) % 2 === 0`. Какое для вас решайте сами

```js
let result = [2,4,5,8,1].filter((item,index) => (item + index + 1) %2===0);
let result1 = [2,4,5,8,1].filter((item,index) => (item + index) %2===0);
       
console.log(result);
console.log(result1);
```